# exec function in php work in terminal but not work in crontab

Tags: php, linux, terminal, cron, exec

I want to suspend a number of system users and disable their processes
When I run this code in the terminal, it runs correctly and the user is blocked and the processes are killed
But when I run it with cron tab, the jobs are not blocked, but the processes are killed

**My php code in controller.php file:**

```
foreach ($usernames as $key => $username) {
        $output = [];
        exec('/usr/sbin/usermod -L -e 1 ' . $key, $output);

        $usernames[$key]['timestamp'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $usernames[$key]['output'] = $output;
        killProccess($username['pids']);
        unset($usernames[$key]['pids']);
    }
```

**My crontab:**

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/myuser/controller.php
```

**User status when I run with terminal:**

```
Last password change                                    : Feb 20, 2023

Password expires                                        : never

Password inactive                                       : never

Account expires                                         : Jan 02, 1970

Minimum number of days between password change          : 0

Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999

Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```

**User status when I run with crontab:**

```
Last password change                                    : Feb 20, 2023

Password expires                                        : never

Password inactive                                       : never

Account expires                                         : never

Minimum number of days between password change          : 0

Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999

Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the command so you capture error messages. Then use `print_r($output)` to see the output.

Comment: Is this running in root's crontab?

Comment: @Barmar $output is empty and crontab is running in root